# PHP Function Calling Function

Tags: php, function, loops

Working on a link shortening script and I'm stumped. I figured the following code would function as needed however, I get an execution time out related to  `$str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];`. I have scoured over the code several times, I can't find what I am doing wrong.

```
function randString($length, $charset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') {
    $str = '';
    $count = strlen($charset);
    while ($length--) {
        $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
    }
    return $str; 
}

function shrinkURL($url) {
    $is_unique = false;
    $num = 4;
    $random_string = randString($num);

    $count = 0;
    while (!$is_unique) {
        $q1 = "SELECT id FROM linkShortner WHERE short = '".$random_string."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

        if ($result === false)   // if you don't get a result, then you're good
            $is_unique = true;
        else                     // if you DO get a result, keep trying
            $count++;

    if ($count >= 10) {
        $num = (strlen($random_string) + 1);
    $random_string = randString($num);
    $count = 0;
        }
    $random_string = randString($num);
    }

    $shortURL = "https://domain.com/l/".$random_string;

    $q2 = "INSERT INTO linkShortner (id, destination, short, shorURL, creationDate) VALUES (NULL, '".$url."', '".$random_string."', '".$shortURL."', '".$DateTime."')";
    $r2 = mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_error());

    return $shortURL; 

}

$shortURL = shrinkURL('http://domain.com');
echo $shortURL;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, think maybe I am just burnt out.

Comment: I got the answer but I cant post it [the answer as answer] due to my reputation being under 10. So here I is: Changed `if ($result === false)` to `if (!mysql_num_rows($result))` and all is well. `if ($result === false)` is for mysqli which is not being used here.

Basically the shrinkURL function scours the DB for a matching string before trying to insert a unique string/row, `if ($result === false)` would never = false because the value of `$result` is `MySQL_query($q1)` therefore producing an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that at some point your function `randString()` will be called with the `$length` argument being 0.

This would make:

```
while ($length--) {
    $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
}
```

get stuck, because the first iteration would be `while (-1)`, which is true. And then `while (-2)`, which is also true.. etc etc etc.

I would change your `while ( $length-- )` to `while ( $length-- >= 0 )`

Comment: If I add the following under the `randString` function It works.

Comment: $num = 4;
    $random_string = randString($num);
    echo $random_string;
    exit();

Comment: You are calling the `randString()` twice in your code. Since the exit makes it work, I'm guessing the second call (in the `if ($count >=10)...` bit) is the one ending up in an endless loop.

Comment: I did try your suggestions out of frustration, though I do appreciate the thought they were not helpful. Changing `while ( $length-- )` to `while ( $length-- >= 0 )` resulted in a string length of 5, I would prefer to start with 4 and only increase the length if there are no more unique strings available quickly. I probably should have been more informative with my question. You were right about the `randString` calls being the culprit due to improper use of `$result` (see comment under my question). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Changed `if ($result === false)` to `if (!mysql_num_rows($result))` and all is well. `if ($result === false)` is for mysqli which is not being used here.

Basically the shrinkURL function scours the DB for a matching string before trying to insert a unique string/row, `if ($result === false)` would never = false because the value of `$result` is `MySQL_query($q1)` therefore producing an endless loop.